# JAVA: Reading and modifying xml

Tags: xml, parsing, jaxb

I need to read the xml file and update the value of some of its properties based on the index. (eg. Message.Person.Name = "XYX", Message.Numbers.Number[1] = 2)

```
<Message>
  <Person>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <Country>USA</Country>
  </Person>
  <Numbers>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Number>2</Number>
  </Numbers>
</Message>
```

The xml structure is different everytime. Is there a way I can convert xml to Java Object dynamically and change the value of necessary property and convert back to xml? Remember, I dont have any specific xsd for my xml structure.
I looked in examples for JAXB and MOXy, but seems they both need xsd.

Comment: If you don't have a stable structure, why do you want to convert to Java object then? Would a simple XPath or XSLT not work?

Comment: Can you please provide a xpath example? I have not done much there.

Comment: You mean like `/Message/Numbers/Number[.='1']`?

Comment: If your XML structure is not stable, you'll probably have some rules on what and how you want to update. Rules would better match an XSLT. JAXB and co. work when you have a stable structure.

Comment: Which library I can use in java to access XML with xpath? You mean if I use DocumentBuilder then I can use xpath to refer element in document?

Comment: Worked with finding the element with xpath and updating it.

Answer (score 1):

If your xml structure really is different every time then it won’t have one stable xsd in the first place.

However, if it is stable enough (e.g. always a Message, with Person elements and Numbers elenents) then [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/) might be an option. It doesn’t need an xsd.

You’d have to define the Message etc classes yourself with getters and setters, then use Jackson’s XmlMapper class to read xml into objects.

Comment: I clearly mentioned that I dont have stable xsd, so obvious cant create any classes. I need the other way to do it.

Comment: You did, and my answer accounts for that. As I said, Jackson does not need an xsd.

Comment: My xml is not even stable enough. It will be completely different every time.

Comment: So: from a constantly changing source? Do people still use streaming parsers? How about STaX? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html

Comment: Thanks. Trying the suggestion.